# On some classical groups with small permutation degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory

The following question arises while I am reading a paper of [B. N. Cooperstein.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02761072)

In the Table 1 of his paper, two groups have smaller permutation degree compared to other members in their family: $\mathrm{PSp}_4(3)$ with permutation degree 27 and $\mathrm{PSU}_3(5)$ with permutation degree 50, while $\mathrm{PSp}_{2n}(q)$ generally has a permutation degree of $$\frac{q^{2n}-1}{q-1}$$ and $\mathrm{PSU}_3(q)$ has a permutation degree of $q^3+1$. It is already known to Camille Jordan that $\mathrm{PSp}_4(3)$ is a permutation group on 27 lines of a cubic surface. I am curious if there is a similar geometric configuration for $\mathrm{PSU}_3(5)$.

**Question:** Is there any neat geometric configuration (with 50 elements) that the group $\mathrm{PSU}_3(5)$ is a permutation group which acts faithfully on the configuration?

---

**Edit:** A table for permutation degree of simple groups can be found [here](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~grizzard/papers/table.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the article by  B. N. Cooperstein is behind a paywall. 
But I think the object you are looking for is the Hoffman–Singleton graph. There is a wikipedia page about that graph, see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoffman%E2%80%93Singleton_graph

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow. Why don't you add a link to the wikipedia page?

Comment: You are right, I have added the link. It just took me some time to find out how to do it.

Comment: perhaps it is also worth mentioning that the degree 27 action of Sp(4,3) arises from its isomorphism to $U(4,2)$, for which the action of degree 27 is the action on totally isotropic lines in its natural 4-dimensional module over GF(4). In the case of  degree 50 action of U(3,5), nothing like this happens.

Comment: I found this table https://www.math.wisc.edu/~grizzard/papers/table.pdf just now. I will put the link in my question.